# My python program won't execute or show anything in the terminal

Tags: python

So I was trying to solve a project Euler question that asks we shoud find the largest prime factor of 600851475143.
This is my code:

```
factors = [i for i in range(1,600851475144) if 600851475143%i is 0]
prime_factors = []
for num in factors:
    factors_of_num = [i for i in range(1, num+1) if num%i is 0]
    if factors_of_num == [1, num]:
        prime_factors.append(num)
print(max(prime_factors))
```

The issue is that this code won't run for a large  number like this. How can \i get this to work?

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'this code won't run'? Do you get an error or what?

Comment: You program _is_ executing, but `range(1,600851475144)` is just taking a rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrreally long time.

Comment: There are much better ways to get prime factors instead of first finding all the divisors and then checking which of those are primes. Hint: As soon as you find a divisor, divide the number by that divisor; this way, all your divisors are guaranteed to be prime, and you will need a lot fewer tests. Also, stop as soon as you hit sqrt(n), as no divisor can be larger than that.

Comment: Yeah, seconded! I ran it and it took a long time, specifically the first line. My Python repl killed itself before it could complete.

Comment: Use [tqdm](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/) to monitor process. It takes 50 minutes to finish the first line of code. You can optimize that (get rid of even numbers for example, cut almost 50% calculations).

Comment: @tobias_k Of course divisors `d` are often larger than `sqrt(n)`.  What you wanted to say is that finding all the ones which are lower than `sqrt(n)` is algorithmically enough because with each one `d1 < sqrt(n)` you also find the corresponding ones `d2 > sqrt(n)` which are higher by computing `d2 = n / d1`.

Comment: @tobias_k Consider 21.  `sqrt(21)` is around 4.58.  The prime factors are 3 and 7.  7 > 4.58.

Comment: @Alfe Whops, you are right, Must have confused something there. Will fix.

Comment: recheck the problem. thats euler 3, no?  it’s extremely easy to take the wrong conceptual approach and launch a very costly loop that doesn’t do anything for hours.  i did it. hint:  start from bottom - small prime that divides first.  then swap target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program *is* executing, but `range(1, 600851475144)` is just taking a rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrreally long time. There are much better ways to get prime factors instead of first checking each number individually whether it is a divisor and then checking which of those are primes.

First, for each pair of divisors `p * q = n`, either `p` or `q` has to be `<= sqrt(n)`, so you'd in fact only have to check the numbers in `range(1, 775147)` to get one part of those pairs and get the other for free. This alone should be enough to make your program finish in time. But you'd still get *all* the divisors, and then have to check which of those are prime.

Next, you do not actually have to get *all* the prime factors of those divisors to determine whether those are prime: You can use `any` to stop as soon as you find the first non-primitive factor. And here, too, testing up to `sqrt(num)` is enough. (Also, you could start with the largest divisor, so you can stop the loop as soon as you find the first one that's prime.)

---

Alternatively, as soon as you find a divisor, divide the target number by that divisor until it can not be divided any more, then continue with the new, smaller target number and the next potential divisor. This way, all your divisors are *guaranteed* to be prime (otherwise the number would already have been reduced by *its* prime factors), and you will also need much fewer tests (unless the number itself is prime).